# Closing a window in OS X Yosemite causes other windows to be made active

Tags: macos, window-manager

I have a Chrome window and this Chrome window covers the whole screen (not in the full screen mode, though). I also have 5 Finder windows under this Chrome window. So I can't see any Finder windows. Now I need a Finder window, so  I use Mission Control. Everything works well, but when I close this Finder window, other all Finder windows show up on top of the screen, I don't need them, I only need one window.

How can I prevent this?

This is happening all apps. Not just in Finder and I am using Yosemite 10.10.

Comment: what window do you expect to show up (become active)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Apple paradigm - all windows belonging to one app are part of a single process, unlike Windows, which is, as the name suggests, windows-based. Apple is App-based. What you are seeing is intended behaviour.

The simplest 'workaround' - though to me an indispensable way to use the machine - is to enable Spaces & the associated hot-keys, then put 'important' apps on a Space of their own & switch using the hot-keys.

[I'm in the middle of teaching someone how to use that method right now in meatworld - a Windows migrant learning the new paradigm - so if you're interested, I'll try to flesh out exactly *how* to go about it.]

Comment: You could also try Witch or Optimal Layout to add Windows alt-tab and other window based behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You're clicking the Finder icon in Mission Control, click ONLY the window you want to display.

Comment: As I said, this is not special for finder. This is happening on all apps.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I think it should work for you now.

Comment: No you got it wrong. I actually clicking just my window to display. When I close this window the other Finder windows shows up.

Comment: Don't close it, click back into Chrome and they should all go to the background.

Comment: That's how it's built to work. if you close the primary window, it will then show you the secondary window which is now the primary window and on and on and on. If you don't want multiple finder windows, use tabs instead of new windows.

Comment: @Zero That's what I put in my original answer. He said that the problem is with all applications that he has multiple windows of, though.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 Not closing the windows is not answer. :) I guess there is no way to resolve this problem. I think apple should fix this.

Comment: I don't think that there is anything really to fix. All Mission Control does is bringing apps and windows to the foreground. You'll have to close them individually, but to close all windows at once, just secondary-click on the app in the dock and then click "Quit <insert app name here>" hope that helps

Comment: It doesn't need 'fixing', it's not broken. It's a different way of working; you're just used to another way.